# Do babies born with lots of hair cause heartburn during pregnancy?

Tags: medical-science, pregnancy

This is a common wives' tale about pregnancy and I heard it many times during the course of the various pregnancies I've recently been near. In particular, one of the infants was born with a full head of hair and I was surprised how frequently people were attributing the constant heartburn during the associated pregnancy to the child's hair.

Has such a connection ever been confirmed?

Comment: Yep, Ive commonly heard this too. Anecdotally my youngest was born with a full head of hair, and no specific complaints of heartburn from the wife.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Yes, there is a connection.

> Heartburn is a normal consequence of pregnancy. The predominant aetiology is a decrease in lower oesophageal sphincter pressure caused by female sex hormones, especially progesterone <sup>[1]</sup>.
>
> Sixty-four pregnant women ranked the severity of their degree of heartburn during pregnancy. Independent coders rated newborn hair volume using 2 photographs of the infant's head, taken shortly after birth. ... The simple linear relationship between heartburn severity and hair volume was significant r(s)(62) = 0.40, p < 0.001 <sup>[2]</sup>.
>
> Contrary to expectations, it appears that an association between heartburn severity during pregnancy and newborn hair does exist. We propose a shared biologic mechanism involving a dual role of pregnancy hormones in both the relaxation of the lower esophageal sphincter and the modulation of fetal hair growth <sup>[2]</sup>.

---

References:

1. Richter JE. [Review article: the management of heartburn in pregnancy.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/16225482) Aliment. Pharmacol. Ther. 2005 Nov 1;22(9):749-57. doi: [10.1111/j.1365-2036.2005.02654.x](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1365-2036.2005.02654.x). PubMed PMID: 16225482.
2. Costigan KA, Sipsma HL, DiPietro JA. [Pregnancy folklore revisited: the case of heartburn and hair.](http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pubmed/17150070) Birth. 2006 Dec;33(4):311-4. doi: [10.1111/j.1523-536X.2006.00128.x](http://dx.doi.org/10.1111/j.1523-536X.2006.00128.x). PubMed PMID: 17150070.

Comment: Wow, awesome. Thanks. I... didn't actually expect this one to be true.